# Scatterplot Matrices - Attributes (R)

Tags: r, matrix, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I'm new to R and I have been experimenting with different data visualization techniques. I was trying out scatter-plot matrices and this is my code

```
scatterplotMatrix(~Salary+Percent_MBA+Percentile_ET, 
              data = placedET,
              main = "Scatter Plot Matrix",
              spread = FALSE,
              )
```

My question is can I access attributes of the red line (non-parametric regression), *can I alter its type?* I found that the color can be altered through `col` but can't I change the line type .I have managed to change the green lines attributes by `lty` but I can't access the other one. I read the help section for scatter-plot matrices and stumbled upon `smoother.args` .Is this related to it somehow? [I've posted an image link to show my current scatter-plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxb9r.png)

(P.S : It's my first question here so I'm sorry if I have made any mistakes. Please point them out.)

Comment: I haven't used that function myself, but looking at the 
 documentation https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/2.1-5/topics/scatterplotMatrix I don't see any arguments for altering the attributes of the non-parametric regression lines.

Comment: The attributes can be changed, if you're interested check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally I got the answer. My initial suspicion was right. To get the lines to be dotted include `smoother.args=list(lty=2) in the code.`